# Can't restrict API access by positional args via external_auth SaltStack

Tags: cherrypy, salt-stack

I'm trying to restrict the calling `state.apply` only for specific SLS files via the pam module.

```yaml
external_auth:
  pam:
    myuser:
      - '@runner':
        - jobs.list_job
      - '*':
        - test.ping
        - 'state.apply':
          args:
           - 'path/to/sls'
```

When I call the API via CherryPy API I get 401.

```sh
curl http://sat_master/run -H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d [{"tgt":"target","arg":["path/to/sls"],"kwarg":{"pillar":{"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2"}},"client":"local_async","fun":"state.apply","username":"myuser","password":"<passwrod>","eauth":"pam"}]
```

What I also tried:

```yaml
external_auth:
  pam:
    myuser:
      - '@runner':
        - jobs.list_job
      - '*':
        - test.ping
        - 'state.apply':
          args:
           - '.*'
```

```yaml
external_auth:
  pam:
    myuser:
      - '@runner':
        - jobs.list_job
      - '*':
        - test.ping
        - 'state.apply':
          args:
           - '.*'
          kwargs:
           '.*' : '.*'
```

If I don't specify `args` it works:

```yaml
external_auth:
  pam:
    myuser:
      - '@runner':
        - jobs.list_job
      - '*':
        - test.ping
        - state.apply
```

How do correctly do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` field should be the field of the function object. I.e. :

**Wrong**:

```yaml
'*':
  - state.apply:
    args:
     - 'path/to/sls'
```

The JSON equivalent

```json
{
  "*": [
    {
      "state.apply": null,
      "args": [
        "path/to/sls"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Right**:

```yaml
'*':
  - state.apply:
      args:
        - 'path/to/sls'
```

The JSON equivalent

```json
{
  "*": [
    {
      "state.apply": {
        "args": [
          "path/to/sls"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is the way how we are passing the values or creating the restrictions.

For example, if you need to create a restriction for the cmd.run and just allow the function with this parameters

```
arg:"shell=powershell"
arg:"[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($pwd.path)"
```

This is what i need in the .conf

The restriction for yourUser, in all the targets - '*' allowing just cmd.run if the arguments are #1 shell=powershell and the secound value is the trick, this is a redex funtion that acepts the value [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($pwd.path)

If i restrict using the value it fails, you need to pass the regular expression
This is a good tool to test your regular expression
https://regex101.com/

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    yourUSer:
      - '*':
        - cmd.run:
            args:
              - 'shell=powershell'
              - '\[System\.Convert\]::ToBase64String\(\$pwd\.path\)'
```

```
curl --location 'https://master:8000' \
--header 'X-Auth-Token: YOURTOKE' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client=local' \
--data-urlencode 'tgt=targetID' \
--data-urlencode 'fun=cmd.run' \
--data-urlencode 'arg=shell=powershell' \
--data-urlencode 'arg=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($pwd.path)'
```